# Show rank with SQL

Tags: mysql

I want to get the "rank" of a specific Name in my database.
So if I type in Julia, I want to get #2. (Her rank/place in the database)

**Name**        **Points**

```
Julia       1987
Marc        1479 
Sophia      2517
```

Comment: Where is your query so far?

Comment: This is not a code-writing service. Provide your attempt and ask a specific question.

Comment: `order by Points` and a windowing function should do the trick. Good luck, tell us your sql statement and where you're stuck so we can give some answer.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I want to output the "rank" of a name that the user can type in. With a SQL Statement. I don't know how to do that. I already searched in the wiki.

Comment: @RikSportel window functions require mariadb 10.2 or (not yet actually available afaict) MySQL 8.0.2

Comment: @ysth yeah you're right, didn't read the MySQL tag, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select rank
from
(
    select name, @rank := @rank + 1 as rank
    from your_table
    cross join (select @rank := 0) r
    order by points desc
) tmp
where name = 'Julia'
```

The inner select orders the data and adds a rank column. The outer select gets the rank of the specific person.